# Inheriting from DispatcherObject

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading

I would like to create a subclass of `DispatcherObject` to create my own thread-affined objects with a message queue, like WPF uses for UI elements.

I have a test app that runs without crashing, but the DispatcherObject doesn't seem to be processing its message queue. I just created a new blank WPF application and added this code to the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherWorker worker = null;
        ManualResetEventSlim latch = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

        new Thread(() => {
            worker = new DispatcherWorker();
            latch.Set();
        }).Start();

        latch.Wait();

        // worker.Dispatcher.Thread is stopped by here... why?
        worker.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            // This code never executed
            worker.DoWork(this);
        }));
    }
}

public class DispatcherWorker : DispatcherObject {

    public void DoWork(MainWindow window) {
        VerifyAccess();
        window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => window.Background = Brushes.Black));
    }
}
```

The `DoWork()` method is never executed, and if I put a breakpoint just before the call to `BeginInvoke`, I see that the Dispatcher's thread is stopped. Why is it stopped? Am I setting up the thread wrong?

([This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864033/dispatcherobject-inheritance-and-usage-what-am-i-not-getting) seems to have the same problem, but the accepted answer says to run the code in a GUI application, which will have a message pump. But I'm getting the same problem even when running in a GUI app.)

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about threading or what you're doing, but won't the `.Wait()` call hang the thread until something is finished, however that something will never get started or finished because the main UI thread is waiting for the constructor to finish?

Comment: @Rachel: The `Wait()` call will only wait until the `ManualResetEventSlim.Set()` call, which happens on the other thread. When I step through the code I can get all the way through the constructor, it's just that the call to `worker.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread that owns the `Dispatcher` will need to "pump" that `Dispatcher`. That is, it will need to be told to process messages queued via that `Dispatcher`. To do this, you use a `DispatcherFrame`:

```
Dispatcher.PushFrame(new DispatcherFrame());
```

This should appear after you set your latch. That thread will never exit - it will just pump messages on that thread's dispatcher. If you want it to have an exit condition, see the documentation for the `DispatcherFrame` [`Continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherframe.continue.aspx) property.

Note that it's irrelevant whether you're using your custom `DispatcherWorker` class or some other built-in WPF class. If there's nothing pumping the `Dispatcher` on that thread, no messages will be processed.

Comment: An alternative means of doing the same thing is to call Dispatcher.Run().

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `worker.Dispatcher` refers to the thread that the `DispatcherObject` (in this case, `DispatcherWorker`) was created on, which would be the `Thread` created in the constructor.

Since that thread has already been started and completed it's work, the current state is `Stopped`. You'll probably have to start it again to run `DoWork()`

You can find more information on the subject [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/08/12/wpf-inside-out-dispatcher.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you have created a thread. And your DispatcherWorker is instantiated in the scope of the created thread, which makes the thread that you created the CurrentThread of your DispatcherWorker .

So, In the BeginInvoke it happens that DispatcherWorker is aborted because PostMessage ("user32.dll") does not pump the message from your DispatcherWorker. If your worker was instantiated outside the scope of the created thread then all will go well there, because his dispatcher is the main thread dispatcher.

In summary, your Worker oborted is because in BeginInvoke there is no possibility of pumping the message.